# How to run an async method synchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

In my method:

```
void myMethod()
{
    // other stuff
    client.PostAsync(url, content);
}
```

I want to post something and don't leave `myMethod` before sending data. It's not possible to make `myMethod` an async method, so how to wait until data has sent completely before leaving `myMethod`?

Comment: you can't - it might be dispatched on another thread.

Comment: are you looking for **await** ?

Comment: what is the type of `client`?

Comment: What is the return value of `PostAsync`?

Comment: Check if the method has a synchronous version

Comment: @Selman22 No, that just makes `myMethod` asynchronous too.

Comment: `myMethod` should return void, I tried `async void myMethod()` and then `await client.PostAsync(url,content);` but it reached to the end before data was sent

Comment: @Selman22 If he awaits then presumably his method has to be async too, which he doesn't want.

Comment: yes, but it won't leave the method until the task is finished. I think that's the question

Comment: `PostAsync` returns `HttpResponseMessage`, but I don't care about its value.

Comment: so why do you want to wait?

Comment: @NedStoyanov because I want to make sure that data has sent completely to the server

Comment: @DanielA.White that other question doesn't help me, I think.